# How put Placeholder on razor code

Tags: c#, forms, razor, placeholder

I have an HTML form with no connection to the database like this:

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Inserir nome">
<input class="input100" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome*">
<span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
```

And now I'm connecting to the database but I can't put the "placeholder" in my code. I tried to put the `"Name:"` but it doesn't work. I don't know very well about this technology, is new for me.

```
<form class="contact100-form validate-form">
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Inserir nome">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerFirstName, "Nome:", new { @class = "control-label" }) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerFirstName, new { @class = "input100" })
@{ Html.ValidateFor(m => m.CustomerFirstName); }

</div>
```

Form template I'm using: https://colorlib.com/etc/cf/ContactFrom_v15/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `placeholder` property to the Html attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerFirstName, new {
    @class = "input100", 
    placeholder = "Nome*" })
```